# data.table merge by multiple columns

Tags: r, merge, data.table

I'm trying to match 4 variables pairwise and add a column with the lookup value. In base, I would do `merge(df1,df2, by.x=c("lsr","ppr"),by.y=c("li","pro"))`, where `df1` has 9 cols and `df2` (2 being `lsr` and `pro`) `df2` has only 3, `li`, `pro`, and the "value" I'm interested in, `alpha`.

This works fine, but as I'm beginning to be a huge fan of `data.table`, I would like to do this in the `data.table` way - and because I have some millions of rows - so base merge is slow (I saw, that the `by.x`, and `by.y` feature is pending for `data.table`, but maybe there is a workaround). See some sample data below:

```
df2:
         alpha         li        pro
      1: 0.5000000 0.01666667 0.01666667
      2: 0.3295455 0.03333333 0.01666667
      3: 0.2435897 0.05000000 0.01666667
      4: 0.1917808 0.06666667 0.01666667
      5: 0.1571429 0.08333333 0.01666667
df1:     
          demand rtime    mcv         mck        ppr       mlv         mlk        lsr
      1:    0.3     1 357.57700 0.099326944 0.01666667 558.27267 0.155075741 0.01666667
      2:    0.3    10 548.75433 0.152431759 0.01666667 614.30667 0.170640741 0.03333333
      3:    0.3    11 314.55767 0.087377130 0.01666667 636.48100 0.176800278 0.03333333
      4:    0.3     2 312.15033 0.086708426 0.01666667 677.48100 0.188189167 0.06666667
      5:    0.3     3 454.47867 0.126244074 0.01666667 608.92067 0.169144630 0.01666667
     ---                                                                               
6899196:    0.6     5 537.92673 0.149424093 1.00000000 537.92673 0.149424093 1.00000000
6899197:    0.6     6 277.34732 0.077040923 1.00000000 277.34732 0.077040923 1.00000000
6899198:    0.6     7  73.31484 0.020365235 1.00000000  73.31484 0.020365235 1.00000000
6899199:    0.6     8  32.04197 0.008900546 1.00000000  32.04197 0.008900546 1.00000000
6899200:    0.6     9  14.59008 0.004052799 1.00000000  14.59008 0.004052799 1.00000000
```

Last, maybe of interest is, that in `df2` I have unique rows, and in `df1`, I have lots of duplicates in respect to `lsr` and `ppr`. I also tried to set two keys and join them the `data.table` way, and adding a new column with `alpha`. But without success.

Comment: If you don't need an outer join, you can just do a left, a right join or an inner join using binary join. The question is which one you want. Though judging by your base R code it seems like you wan an inner join? Also, which column you want to keep? You also don't have `pro` column in `df1`

Comment: Thanks. Actually I believe, in this case the inner and the left joins are the same, as all combinations of lsr and ppr, or of li and pro are included in both df1 and df2. And not having pro in df1 is a typo!! Sorry for that, I meant, ppr in df1, I'll edit and correct it. I'd like to keep all columns from df1 and add alpha as a new column

Comment: If all you need is a left join to `df1` while updating `alpha` column, it is a simple binary join. Try `setkey(df1, lsr, ppr) ; setkey(df2, li, pro) ; df1[df2, alpha := i.alpha] ; df1`

Comment: Ha! thats it! Thanks a lot. I knew it was easy. Actually I tried that version, but I didn't know about the i. Just one follow-up, what's the need for the i. before alpha?

Comment: So if you already have an `alpha` column in your `df1` set, `i` will tell `data.table` to get the information from the `alpha` in `df2`. It is always safer to put `i,` before the column names on the RHS in order to avoid possible unexpected results.

Comment: OK. now I'm really a fan of data.table. Thanks!

Comment: You have my upvote as fellow "great fan of data.table". That package is music to my fingers, poetry to my scripts!

Answer (score 28, accepted):

You can use the statement provided by David Arenburg in comment:

```
setkey(df1, lsr, ppr)
setkey(df2, li, pro)
df1[df2, alpha := i.alpha]
```

---

From the [current devel version, 1.9.5](https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/wiki/Installation), we can perform joins directly without having to set keys using the `on` argument:

```
df1[df2, alpha := i.alpha, on = c(lsr="li", ppr="pro")]
```

If you don't want to install the devel version, then you can wait until this is pushed as v1.9.6 on CRAN.

Comment: Is df1[df2, alpha := i.alpha] supposed to add a column to df1? It's not doing anything for me.

Comment: yes, please submit bug report to data.table repository providing reproducible example and session info