# How to use specify and extract variables from X and Y in the non-equi join X[Y, ...]?

Tags: r, data.table

This question gives an example on how to convert the `by.x =` and `by.y =` arguments in base `R` `merge` to `data.table` syntax, to specify differently named columns as the join key:

[data.table merge by multiple columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30370879/data-table-merge-by-multiple-columns)

However, I can't work out how to do the same for a non-equi join, and I am very confused by the output.

Example data:

```
set.seed(0)
tmp_dt1<- data.table(grp = c(1,2), time = runif(100))
tmp_dt2 <- data.table(grp = c(1,2), time = c(0.1, 0.5))
tmp_dt2 <- tmp_dt2[, time_to := time + 0.2]
tmp_dt2 <- tmp_dt2[, time_from := time] # for clarity, rename time variable
```

I would like to equi-join the two tables by `grp`, followed by a non-equi join so that I only keep `time` from `tmp_dt1` where it falls between `time_to` and `time_from`. From what I can tell `tmp_dt1[tmp_dt2, , on = c("grp", "time>=time", "time<=time_to")]` does what I want:

```
> tmp_dt1[tmp_dt2, , on = c("grp", "time>=time", "time<=time_to")]
    grp time time.1 time_from
 1:   1  0.1    0.3       0.1
 2:   1  0.1    0.3       0.1
 3:   1  0.1    0.3       0.1
 4:   1  0.1    0.3       0.1
 5:   1  0.1    0.3       0.1
 6:   1  0.1    0.3       0.1
 7:   1  0.1    0.3       0.1
...
```

What confuses me is that `x.time` is missing, and the resulting column names are very confusing. For example, why is there a column called `time.1`? I would like to clarify the syntax so that `tmp_dt1[tmp_dt2, , on = c("grp", "time>=y.time", "time<=y.time_to")]` produces:

```
    grp y.time y.time_to time_from
 1:   1  0.1    0.3       0.1
 2:   1  0.1    0.3       0.1
 3:   1  0.1    0.3       0.1
 4:   1  0.1    0.3       0.1
 5:   1  0.1    0.3       0.1
 6:   1  0.1    0.3       0.1
 7:   1  0.1    0.3       0.1
...
```

and some how also extract the column `x.time`, in addition to all columns in `y`. Unfortunately this fails with the error:

```
> tmp_dt1[tmp_dt2, , on = c("grp", "time>=y.time", "time<=y.time_to")]
Error in `[.data.table`(tmp_dt1, tmp_dt2, , on = c("grp", "time>=y.time",  : 
  Column(s) [y.time,y.time_to] not found in i
```

Trying the following also does not produce what I expect, instead I get:

```
> tmp_dt1[tmp_dt2, .(grp, time, time_from = i.time, time_to = i.time_to), on = c("grp", "time>=time", "time<=time_to")]
    grp time time_from time_to
 1:   1  0.1       0.1     0.3
 2:   1  0.1       0.1     0.3
 3:   1  0.1       0.1     0.3
 4:   1  0.1       0.1     0.3
 5:   1  0.1       0.1     0.3
 6:   1  0.1       0.1     0.3
 7:   1  0.1       0.1     0.3
```

where the `time` column bears no resemblance to `tmp_dt1$time`.

Comment: ok, as far as I can tell, the following rules for join key matching apply if the `on` condition is supplied using `.()` or `c()` in `X[Y]`. If each element contains one variable, then look for that variable in both tables. If variables are supplied on either side of an equation, then look for LHS variable in `X` table and RHS variable in `Y` table. The variable extraction and final column names are still a mystery to me.

Comment: Final column names are always from Y. There is one join column for each entry in `on=`.

Comment: You might want to clarify the expected result. Here's one fairly reasonable thing to go for: `tmp_dt1[tmp_dt1[tmp_dt2, on = .(grp, time >= time_from, time <= time_to), which=TRUE]]` subsetting the first table. I doubt there's much point in hanging onto the lower and upper bounds as repeating values.

Comment: thanks @Frank, I changed a few sentences. What I meant was that I wanted the original `time` column from the first data table.

Comment: @Frank, what do you mean by "final column names are always from Y". For example, `tmp_dt1[tmp_dt2, on = .(grp, time >= time_from, time <= time_to)]` does not produce a `time_from` and `time_to` column.

Comment: It looks like something like manually setting the column names: `tmp_dt1[tmp_dt2[, time := NULL], .(time = x.time, time_from, time_to), on = .(grp, time >= time_from, time <= time_to)]` does what I want, but I am still very confused on why this works, and why it is necessary to use `x.time` even when `time` is not a column in `Y`.

Comment: Yeah, sorry, I meant to say final column values. A join is `x[i]` (using the actual argument names), and it can be thought of as using rows of `i` to look up rows of `x`. For this reason, we end up with values from `i` in the result. At least that's how I think of it. To me, the column names are a sideshow and fairly easily customized...

Comment: I understand about confusing names (something that needs fixing). In the meanwhile, see if [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44343424/559784) helps..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To prevent confusion i would suggest to rename columns that have the same name in both data.tables and create copies of the columns of non-equi join columns.

`setnames(tmp_dt2, "time", "time_dt2")
tmp_dt2[, c("time_from_join", "time_to_join"):=list(time_from, time_to)]
tmp_dt1[ , time_join := time]`

Then we can join and then throw away all the temporary columns that data.table messes with in the non-equi join.

`tmp_dt1[tmp_dt2, on=.(grp==grp, time_join >= time_from_join, time_join <= time_to_join)][ , c("grp", "time", "time_from", "time_to", "time_dt2")]`

`grp      time time_from time_to time_dt2
 1:   1 0.1079436       0.1     0.3      0.1
 2:   1 0.1216919       0.1     0.3      0.1
 3:   1 0.1255551       0.1     0.3      0.1
 4:   1 0.1433044       0.1     0.3      0.1
...`

Answer (score 1):

I think you want something like this, using `dplyr`:

```
library(dplyr)
merged <- inner_join(tmp_dt1, tmp_dt2, by="grp") %>%
          rowwise() %>% 
          filter(between(time.x, time_from, time_to)) %>%
          ungroup()
```

`inner_join` equi-joins by `grp1`. `rowwise()` specifies that I want the following statements to occur by row. `filter()` will filter rows by a condition. The condition uses `between` which asks is `time.x >= time_from` and `time.x <= time_to`. Finally, `ungroup` by row, in case you want a *normal* `data.frame`.

Comment: Thank you for this, unfortunately I am pretty sure that this non-equi join using dplyr requires far more memory than the data.table version.

Comment: Why not use data.table join and then pipe to dplyr filter?

Comment: the data.table join (non-equi part) already does the filtering. In any case, my problem is controlling the input and outputs of the join.